# How to set the heightof a snackbar?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, snackbar

I produce the following snackbar with the following code:

Snackbar:
[Snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aso.jpg)

Code:

```
View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Wähle mindestens eine Kategorie aus, um fortzufahren", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                })
                .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple ));
        snackbar.show();
```

As you see, the snackbar is pretty big and I actually only want it to be displayed in the area of the red box. Do you know how to adjust that?

Comment: tried the same code and everything seems ok!

Answer (score 0):

It must bug around with the other Widgets of the `Layout`. Try to make only one `Button` and add Widgets step by step. Then you will find out.

I improved your Code a bit and used one `Button` and the `Snackbar` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_snackbar);
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Wähle mindestens eine Kategorie aus, um fortzufahren", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("CLOSE", view1 -> {
                    })
                    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple));
            snackbar.show();
        });
    }
}
```

**PROVE:**

[image: Snackbar]